# How to sort object by key through JSON file parsing in D3.js

Tags: javascript, html, json, d3.js

I have a JSON file (`myfile.json`) that looks like this:

```
{"3":["c","d"], "3.5":["j","k"], "1.5":["a","b"], "2.5":["x","y"] }
```

What I want to do open the file and sort it using d3.js file opening.

```
 d3.json('myfile.json',function(err,datafull){
    for (var myval in datafull) {
        console.log(myval);
    }
  });
```

Now if I do that, the console.log will print they key in unsorted manner.
How can I sort the file?

This is different question, because it involves file parsing.

Comment: Put each item into an array and then sort the array. Or use `Object.keys()` to get an array of the keys, sort *that* array, then use it to access the properties of the original object in sorted order. But you can't sort a (non-array) object.

Comment: @nnnnnn: How do you put the file into the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sort object keys you can use Object.keys() method which gives an array of the given objects keys then you can use the array sort() method.

```
d3.json('myfile.json',function(err,data){
  keys = Object.keys(data),
  i, len = keys.length;
  keys.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  });

  for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
  {
    var a = keys[i];
    console.log(a + ':' + data[a]);
  }
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/sjmcpherso/mvrWb/234/

Comment: how do you store `myfile.json` to `myObj`?

Comment: Your output is already appears to be an object, is that not the case?

Comment: I need to start from input JSON file.

Comment: neversaint - The `datafull` variable in the code in the question appears to already be an object, so where this answer has `myObj` you'd just substitute `datafull`.

Comment: @sjm - note that `.sort()` with no comparator callback will do a lexical sort, and I suspect the OP wants a numeric sort.

Comment: @nnnnnn thats true, I've added function expression to compare numbers, otherwise it would sort values like: 1.5, 10.5, 3, 3.5

Comment: @sjm: in your example script. Can you put the file name as part of the whole code?

Comment: I've updated my answer but that all depends if 'data' is actually an object which I'm guessing it is